# wp v2 rest request from Android App overload CPU usage

Tags: android, wordpress, performance, mobile, wordpress-rest-api

I have created Android App for news website (wordpress), i used WP v2 API to get posts from database, the problem that even less than 10 users that using the App in same time can overload the server (CPU usage).

When user open the App i send `get` request (using retrofit2) and get the first page (json array with 10 objects of that represent posts).

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=1
```

Then for every post i send another request for media to get image.

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/media/21342
```

Without the App the server overloads when 600-700 users browse the website, with the App it overloads at 300 users and 10 App users.

Why it happen what is the difference between wp-v2 request and browser website loading?

Comment: Are you using any caching configuration? APIs usually don't get included in caching by default, and thus won't profit from it. Have you made sure (by checking access logs etc) that the app doesn't continuously hit the server with requests due to some bug?

Comment: Just need to install plugin or there are special configurations?

Comment: if this is happening trough the app, will happen when accessing the site. Maybe your app is making continuous requests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reduce the number of requests by passing down the image URL with the inital request. I have done this using this `embedded` parameter:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/linking-and-embedding/

Additionally, maybe try using something like S3 Offload Media plugin to serve your images off of a different server than your application server.

Pantheon has a whole site dedicated to WP at Scale: https://scalewp.io

Answer (score 1):

Don't load the detail unless the user taps it to reduce strain on the wordpress server.  The browser is loading as needed is why the increase on CPU.  Your app appears to be loading in advance for items that may never be viewed.